# Search date with the condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx, conditional-statements

I have a model, where define block looks like:

```
define_index do
  indexes title, content, manager, note, start_date, end_date

  has created_at, updated_at

  has user_id, :as => :user_id, :type => :integer

  set_property :delta => true
end
```

I want to search tasks by date, which can fall into the gap between start_date..end_date , how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a standard Active Record SQL call. Since you're passing it parameters, you can do a hashed query like so:

```
    tasks = Task.where("start_date > :start_date and end_date < :end_date", {:start_date => start_date, :end_date => end_date})
```

Drop that in a method that supplies start_date and end_date like so:

```
def tasks_within_range(start_date, end_date)
  Task.where("start_date > :start_date and end_date < :end_date {:start_date => start_date, :end_date => end_date})
end
```

and you've got a dynamic finder! :)

Comment: Sorry, I realized you're just asking for one date with the query. You would set up the query the same, but use a single date for both parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to have start_date and end_date as attributes, not fields:

```
define_index do
  indexes title, content, manager, note

  has created_at, updated_at, start_date, end_date
  has user_id, :as => :user_id, :type => :integer

  set_property :delta => true
end
```

And then, you'll use ranges to limit results on those two attributes:

```
today = Date.today.to_time # or whatever you like
Task.search :with => {
  :start_date => (Time.at(0)..date),
  :end_Date   => (date..Time.at(2 ** 32))
}
```

That should do the job - or perhaps add a `+ 1.day` to the second range. Tweak as you need.

Comment: Pat thanks for answer!But if I make these field attributes not indexes , I can not find the date on them type 2011-04-13 .. etc
And yet, if I instead enter 2011-04-13 into sphinx_scope  console swears and writes an error
ArgumentError: bad value for range

Comment: Sphinx requires actual Time objects (or integers or floats, depending on the attribute) - it's not as forgiving as a normal database. While you need these columns as attributes for the filtering, you can also have them as fields - just give them alternative names: `indexes start_date, :as => :start_string`.

Comment: Pat can i using standart rails3 "scope" in model , for result filtering without thinking_sphinx :with ?! i try Task.filter.search(''), but scope fitler not worked!i asked because your sample didn't work :( i see error  undefined method `at' for Date:Class

Comment: ActiveRecord scopes are for SQL queries - they won't have any impact on Sphinx searches. You'll need to use Sphinx scopes if you'd like that kind of syntax: http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/scopes.html